# Using a class that has params inside another class (PHP)

Tags: php, class

I am trying to access the results of a function that is public inside another class, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this. The class i'm trying to access require parameters, so the class_name::function() method is not working. I'm still new to working with classes, and trying to learn it.

Class one:

```
class foo {
  private $var1;
  function __construct($param) {
    $this->var1 = $param
  }
  public function myFunc() {
    echo $this->var1;
  }
}
```

Class 2

```
class bar {
  public function secondFunc() {
    var_dump(**RESULT FROM foo->myFunc HERE);
  }
}
```

These two classes are a basic example of what i'm actually doing, but from this you should get the general idea of my question.
For the correct result to display, the first class needs the params passed to it otherwise the function fails.
I tried using foo::bar(), but this doesn't pass any params to the first class, and it therefor fails.
So, how do I access myFunc from foo inside secondFunc from bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an instance of foo to bar:

```
class Foo {

  private $var1;

  function __construct($param) {

    $this->var1 = $param
  }

  public function myFunc() {

    return $this->var1;
  }
}

class Bar {

  private $foo;

  function __construct(Foo $foo) {

    $this->foo = $foo
  }

  public function secondFunc() {

    var_dump($this->foo->myFunc());
  }
}

$bar = new Bar(new Foo('something'));
$bar->secondFunc();
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
class bar {
  public function secondFunc() {
    $foo = new foo($param);
    var_dump($foo->myFunc());
  }
}
```

Or do you need something in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't very practical but here is the basic idea

```
public function secondFunc($dependency) {
    var_dump($dependency->myFunc());
}
```

or...

```
public function secondfunc() {
    $foo = new foo();
    var_dump($foo->myFunc();
}
```